# Launching another App by knowing its App Name (not package name)

Tags: android, android-intent, speech-recognition, android-package-managers

I currently have created an engine which accepts voice as input and then converts it to a string. 
Now I wanted to add an option where the voice commands will specify an app name and I will open it. 
For example my voice input was - 'open facebook' then this gets converted into a String.

Now I am trying to make the application launch 'facebook'.
I know that this can be done by using a few methods out of PackageManager, but I am not sure how. 
The current methods suggest making a listview which is not practical for my application. 
Even a small snippet would be very helpful. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: get all installed apps with names and package names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look in the answers [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon). You can get a list with all of the installed apps in the device. Search in the list for the name of the app you need. In that way you got both the name and the package available!

```
class PInfo {
    private String appname = "";
    private String pname = "";
    private String versionName = "";
    private int versionCode = 0;
    private Drawable icon;
    private void prettyPrint() {
        Log.v(appname + "\t" + pname + "\t" + versionName + "\t" + versionCode);
    }
}


private ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {
    ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
    final int max = apps.size();
    for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
        apps.get(i).prettyPrint();
    }
    return apps;
}


private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
    ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
            continue ;
        }
        PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
        res.add(newInfo);
    }
    return res; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I am confused how to search the app name within this. Should I call the object newInfo to compare the name or should I go around and search it against the ArrayList res. 
Can you put forward the code ?

Comment: You can call getPackages and iterate through it, to check which PInfo has the name you are looking for. As soon as you find that, use the package name to start the app. 
Both solution  you suggested sound feasible.

Comment: I can happily say that I did, thanks for your answer there, although it could have been more descriptive. 
I have another question please check and see if you can help there too.